# Can't use .len of a bidimensional array

Tags: zig

I have this simple code that doesn't compile.

```
const s = [_][_]int {
    [_]int{08, 02, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00},
    [_]int{49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18},
    [_]int{81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14},
    [_]int{52, 70, 95, 23, 04, 60, 11},
    [_]int{22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63},
    [_]int{24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 03, 45},
    [_]int{32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67},
    [_]int{67, 26, 20, 68, 02, 62, 12},
    [_]int{24, 55, 58, 05, 66, 73, 99},
    [_]int{21, 36, 23, 09, 75, 00, 76}
};

pub fn main() void
{
    const w = s[0].len;
    const h = s.len;
}
```

The compiler says:

```
./a.zig:1:14: error: inferred array size invalid here
const s = [_][_]int {
             ^
./a.zig:16:15: note: referenced here
    const w = s[0].len;
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be interested to know there's a deeper reason, but my simple understanding is that the current syntax `[N]T` allows for the array size to be elided using `_`, but not for more than one dimension.

So you can fix your problem using the following (N.B. I've used `u8` because I'm unsure what your `int` is):

```
const s = [_][7]u8{
  // Your items
}
```

I suspect this is because of the way the parsing rules are applied, so `[7]u8` would be the type your nested array would hold, and will be used by the compiler to check contents are all of type `[7]u8`; you can confirm this by modifying one of your rows to have 6 elements and examining the resulting error.

If you want a variable number of items, you could start to look into an array of slices: `[_][]u8`, but I don't think that's what you're currently after.

Comment: Yep, it works like this: https://godbolt.org/z/7EoMWd. The `int` was my mistake. It's weird that this code compiles eventhough `int` doesn't exist: https://godbolt.org/z/PjxnYG

Comment: It compiles because the declaration for s is never analyzed, since it is never referenced. The compiler will complain if you try to use it: https://godbolt.org/z/GoEhYYYM7